# How to creat a temporary table using existing tables with their records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

How to create a temporary table using existing tables with their records in MySQL? These are five tables and I want to apply an `UPDATE` query. So when I run the query how it finds the real table and update it.

```
_________________
table1 VALUES   |
|  ID | NAMES   |
|  1  | name1   |
|  2  | name2   |
|  3  | name3   |
|  4  | name4   |
|  5  | name5   |
|  6  | name6   |
|  7  | name7   |
________________|
table2 VALUES   |
|  ID | NAMES   |
|  8  | name8   |
|  9  | name9   |
|  10 | name10  |
|  11 | name11  |
|  12 | name12  |
|  13 | name13  |
|  14 | name14  |
________________|
table3 VALUES   |
|  ID | NAMES   |
|  15 | name15  |
|  16 | name16  |
|  17 | name17  |
|  18 | name18  |
|  19 | name19  |
|  20 | name20  |
|  21 | name21  |
________________|
table4 VALUES   |
|  ID | NAMES   |
|  22 | name22  |
|  23 | name23  |
|  24 | name24  |
|  25 | name25  |
|  26 | name26  |
|  27 | name27  |
|  28 | name28  |
________________|
table1 VALUES   |
|  ID | NAMES   |
|  29 | name29  |
|  30 | name30  |
|  31 | name31  |
|  32 | name32  |
|  33 | name33  |
|  34 | name34  |
|  35 | name35  |
________________|
```

And I want to list them in temporary file like that:

```
_________________
TEMP VALUES     |
|  ID | NAMES   |
|  1  | name1   |
|  2  | name2   |
|  3  | name3   |
|  4  | name4   |
|  5  | name5   |
|  6  | name6   |
|  7  | name7   |
|  8  | name8   |
|  9  | name9   |
|  10 | name10  |
|  11 | name11  |
|  12 | name12  |
|  13 | name13  |
|  14 | name14  |
|  15 | name15  |
|  16 | name16  |
|  17 | name17  |
|  18 | name18  |
|  19 | name19  |
|  20 | name20  |
|  21 | name21  |
|  22 | name22  |
|  23 | name23  |
|  24 | name24  |
|  25 | name25  |
|  26 | name26  |
|  27 | name27  |
|  28 | name28  |
|  29 | name29  |
|  30 | name30  |
|  31 | name31  |
|  32 | name32  |
|  33 | name33  |
|  34 | name34  |
|  35 | name35  |
________________|
```

How can I do it? Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68e62) for the test tables.

Comment: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68e62) test tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below will return your data in desired format. Then you can decide what do you want to put it into. Create a table or a view with `CREATE TABLE | VIEW`.

```
select ID, Name from Table1
UNION ALL
select ID, Name from Table2
UNION ALL
select ID, Name from Table3
UNION ALL
select ID, Name from Table4
UNION ALL
select ID, Name from Table5
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new table and insert values from other tables and repeat for every table.

```
CREATE TABLE table6 (
  ID INT,
  Name6 VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO table6
SELECT * FROM table1;

INSERT INTO table6
SELECT * FROM table2;

...
...
```

Comment: bana lazım olan o değil ki bana temporary table lazım. geçici tablo üzerinde işlem yapmam lazım

Comment: Temporary table'i boyle yapiyorsun iste. Sen nasil temporary table yapilacagini sormussun. Bu tablei kullanarak islem yapmayi mi soruyorsun?